# Recycler view not showing after parsing json data

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

I was using static data to populate the recycler view to test. Now after using dynamic data by parsing json the recycler view is not showing up. I have used console to check whether the JSON is getting parsed correctly and it shows correct results. 
Here is my activity code.

```
package com.paaltao.activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.NetworkError;
import com.android.volley.NoConnectionError;
import com.android.volley.ParseError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.ServerError;
import com.android.volley.TimeoutError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.github.mrengineer13.snackbar.SnackBar;
import com.paaltao.Adapters.CategoryAdapter;
import com.paaltao.R;
import com.paaltao.classes.Category;
import com.paaltao.classes.Product;
import com.paaltao.classes.SharedPreferenceClass;
import com.paaltao.network.VolleySingleton;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static com.paaltao.extras.Keys.ProductList.KEY_DATA;
import static com.paaltao.extras.Keys.ProductList.KEY_ERROR_CODE;
import static com.paaltao.extras.Keys.UserCredentials.*;
import static com.paaltao.extras.Keys.ProductList.*;
import static com.paaltao.extras.urlEndPoints.BASE_URL;
import static com.paaltao.extras.urlEndPoints.CATEGORY_LIST;
import static com.paaltao.extras.urlEndPoints.FEATURED_LIST;
import static com.paaltao.extras.urlEndPoints.UAT_BASE_URL;

public class CategoryActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    Long id;
    private JSONArray categoryListArray;
    String accessToken = "67drd56g",imageURL,categoryName;
    CategoryAdapter categoryAdapter;
    CategoryActivity activity;
    private ArrayList<Category> categoryArrayList = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_category);
        sendJsonRequest();
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.category_grid_recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(activity,getApplicationContext());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) this.findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        this.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        this.setTitle("Categories");

    }

    public void sendJsonRequest(){
        final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        final JSONObject categoryList = new JSONObject();
        try{
            jsonObject.put("accessToken",accessToken);
            categoryList.put("categoryList",jsonObject);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        RequestQueue requestQueue = VolleySingleton.getsInstance().getRequestQueue();
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, getRequestUrl(),categoryList, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {

                categoryArrayList = parseJsonResponse(jsonObject);
                categoryAdapter.setCategoryArrayList(categoryArrayList);

                Log.e("categoryList",categoryArrayList.toString());
                new SnackBar.Builder(CategoryActivity.this)
                        .withMessage(jsonObject.toString())
                        .withTextColorId(R.color.white)
                        .withDuration((short) 6000)
                        .show();
                Log.e("url", UAT_BASE_URL + CATEGORY_LIST);
                Log.e("input_payload",categoryList.toString());
                Log.e("error", jsonObject.toString());
                Log.e("json", categoryList.toString());
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                if (volleyError instanceof TimeoutError || volleyError instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                    new SnackBar.Builder(CategoryActivity.this)
                            .withMessage("No Internet Connection!")
                            .withTextColorId(R.color.white)
                            .withDuration((short) 6000)
                            .show();

                } else if (volleyError instanceof AuthFailureError) {

                    //TODO
                } else if (volleyError instanceof ServerError) {

                    //TODO
                } else if (volleyError instanceof NetworkError) {

                    //TODO
                } else if (volleyError instanceof ParseError) {

                    //TODO
                }

            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
    public static String getRequestUrl() {

        return UAT_BASE_URL
                + CATEGORY_LIST;

    }

    public ArrayList<Category> parseJsonResponse(JSONObject response) {
        ArrayList<Category> categoryArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (response != null && response.length() > 0) {

            try {
                JSONObject dataObject = response.getJSONObject(KEY_DATA);

                if (dataObject.has(KEY_CATEGORY_LIST)) {
                    categoryListArray = dataObject.getJSONArray(KEY_CATEGORY_LIST);
                    for (int i = 0; i < categoryListArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject categoryListObject = categoryListArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        id = categoryListObject.getLong(KEY_CATEGORY_ID);
                        categoryName = categoryListObject.getString(KEY_CATEGORY_NAME);
                        imageURL = categoryListObject.getString(KEY_CATEGORY_IMAGE);


                        Category category = new Category();
                        category.setCategory_id(id);
                        category.setCategory_name(categoryName);
                        category.setImageURL(imageURL);

                        categoryArrayList.add(category);

                        Log.e("id",id.toString());
                        Log.e("image URL", imageURL);
                        Log.e("name",categoryName);

                    }
                }
                if (response.has(KEY_ERROR_CODE)) {
                    JSONObject errorObject = response.getJSONObject(KEY_ERROR_CODE);
                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return categoryArrayList;
    }


}
```

I am also providing the code for the adapter and the layout containing the recycler view

Here is my adapter code:

```
package com.paaltao.Adapters;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.paaltao.R;
import com.paaltao.activity.CategoryActivity;
import com.paaltao.activity.ProductDetailsActivity;
import com.paaltao.activity.ProductListActivity;
import com.paaltao.classes.Category;
import com.paaltao.classes.Product;
import com.paaltao.network.VolleySingleton;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Arindam on 02-Feb-15.
 */
public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.CategoryHolder> {
    private Context context;
    CategoryActivity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private View view;
    private VolleySingleton singleton;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private ArrayList<Category> categoryArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public CategoryAdapter(CategoryActivity activity, Context context){
        this.context = context;
        this.activity = activity;
        singleton = VolleySingleton.getsInstance();
        imageLoader = singleton.getImageLoader();
    }

    @Override
    public CategoryHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_card, parent, false);

        CategoryHolder holder = new CategoryHolder(view);
        holder.categoryImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(activity,ProductListActivity.class);
                activity.startActivity(intent);

                }
        });
        return holder;
    }
    public void setCategoryArrayList(ArrayList<Category> categoryArrayList){
        this.categoryArrayList = categoryArrayList;
        notifyItemRangeChanged(0, categoryArrayList.size());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CategoryHolder holder, int position) {

        Category current = categoryArrayList.get(position);
        holder.categoryName.setText(current.getCategory_name());

        final String imageURL = current.getImageURL();

        if(imageURL != null){
            imageLoader.get(imageURL, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer imageContainer, boolean b) {
                    holder.categoryImage.setImageBitmap(imageContainer.getBitmap());
                    Log.e("imageURLAdapter",imageURL);

                }

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    Log.e("imageURL","no image found");

                }
            });
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return categoryArrayList.size();
    }

    class CategoryHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView categoryName;
        ImageView categoryImage;

        public CategoryHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            categoryImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_image);
            categoryName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_name);

        }
    }
}
```

below is the code for the layout containing recycler view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e2e2e2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar" />


    <!-- A RecyclerView with some commonly used attributes -->


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/category_grid_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"

        />

</LinearLayout>
```

and lastly here is the code for the recycler view row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="false">

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/category_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/apple_small"
            android:contentDescription="@string/category_image_text" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/transparentOverlay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/black99" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/category_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="Handicrafts"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

The activity displays no recycler view at all but the log displays correct JSON data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give a call to notifyDataSetChanged() on Adapter after adding data to the list.

if that doesn't work. try this

change your constructor like this

```
...
private ArrayList<Category> categoryArrayList;

    public CategoryAdapter(CategoryActivity activity, Context context,ArrayList<Category> categoryArrayList){
        this.context = context;
        this.activity = activity;
        singleton = VolleySingleton.getsInstance();
        imageLoader = singleton.getImageLoader();
        this.categoryArrayList = categoryArrayList;
    }
```

and call notifyDataSetChanged()() on CategoryAdapter after adding data to JSON Parsing.

Comment: but I have added notifyItemRangeChanged(0, categoryArrayList.size()); already

Comment: I think its just telling the count of the items, you wanted to notify the adapter that the entire data got changed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77442/discussion-between-shifar-shifz-and-arindam-dawn).